# How to find winstreak/losstreak from array of match history?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, database, filter

I have 2 tables with data of a soccer match:
[image: Table 1 showcases player stats, Table 2, showcases match history]

I have an array called playerNames, which puts all of team 1 and all of team 2 in one array:

```
console.log(playerNames) // [['Pranav', 'Aryan', 'Kedar'], ['Soham', 'Roshan', 'Kunal', 'Sahil'], ['Soham', 'Roshan', 'Kanda'], ['Pranav', 'Sahil', 'Kedar']...]
```

I then split playerNames into two arrays, called winningTeams, and losingTeams:

```
console.log(winningTeams) // [['Soham', 'Roshan', 'Kunal', 'Sahil'], ['Soham', 'Roshan', 'Kanda']...]

console.log(losingTeams) // [['Pranav', 'Aryan', 'Kedar'], ['Pranav', 'Sahil', 'Kedar']...]
```

The way I've determined which team won and which team lost is not by calculating scores but rather giving them the variables `winners` or `losers` in my HTML.

I want to calculate wins treaks or loss streaks (whichever one the player is on), for each player, can someone point me in the right direction.

This is my whole code, if needed:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sporting Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="stats table-sortable styled-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Player<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>MP<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>W<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>L<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>WR<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>WS<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
          <th>LS<i class="fas fa-sort" style="color: #ffffff"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="pranavData">
          <td class="player">Pranav</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedPranav"></td>
          <td class="PranavWins"></td>
          <td class="PranavLosses"></td>
          <td class="PranavWinrate"></td>
          <td class="PranavWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="PranavLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aryanData">
          <td class="player">Aryan</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedAryan"></td>
          <td class="AryanWins"></td>
          <td class="AryanLosses"></td>
          <td class="AryanWinrate"></td>
          <td class="AryanWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="AryanLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="kedarData">
          <td class="player">Kedar</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedKedar"></td>
          <td class="KedarWins"></td>
          <td class="KedarLosses"></td>
          <td class="KedarWinrate"></td>
          <td class="KedarWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="KedarLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sohamData">
          <td class="player">Soham</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedSoham"></td>
          <td class="SohamWins"></td>
          <td class="SohamLosses"></td>
          <td class="SohamWinrate"></td>
          <td class="SohamWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="SohamLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="roshanData">
          <td class="player">Roshan</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedRoshan"></td>
          <td class="RoshanWins"></td>
          <td class="RoshanLosses"></td>
          <td class="RoshanWinrate"></td>
          <td class="RoshanWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="RoshanLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="kunalData">
          <td class="player">Kunal</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedKunal"></td>
          <td class="KunalWins"></td>
          <td class="KunalLosses"></td>
          <td class="KunalWinrate"></td>
          <td class="KunalWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="KunalLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sahilData">
          <td class="player">Sahil</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedSahil"></td>
          <td class="SahilWins"></td>
          <td class="SahilLosses"></td>
          <td class="SahilWinrate"></td>
          <td class="SahilWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="SahilLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="kandaData">
          <td class="player">Kanda</td>
          <td class="matchesPlayedKanda"></td>
          <td class="KandaWins"></td>
          <td class="KandaLosses"></td>
          <td class="KandaWinrate"></td>
          <td class="KandaWinStreak"></td>
          <td class="KandaLossStreak"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="matches styled-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Team 1</th>
          <th>T1 Score</th>
          <th>T2 Score</th>
          <th>Team 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="date">12/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team losers">Pranav Aryan Kedar</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">11</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">29</td>
          <td class="team winners">Soham Roshan Kunal Sahil</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="date">13/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team winners">Soham Roshan Kanda</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">10</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">7</td>
          <td class="team losers">Pranav Sahil Kedar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="date">15/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team losers">Soham Pranav Sahil Kedar</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">14</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">15</td>
          <td class="team winners">Aryan Roshan Kunal</td>
        </tr>

        <!--DUMMY DATA-->
        <tr>
          <td class="date">15/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team losers">Pranav Sahil Roshan</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">14</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">15</td>
          <td class="team winners">Aryan Kedar Kunal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="date">15/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team losers">Soham Kedar Sahil Kunal</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">14</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">15</td>
          <td class="team winners">Aryan Roshan Pranav</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="date">15/08/2023</td>
          <td class="team losers">Pranav Sahil Aryan</td>
          <td class="score teamOneScore">14</td>
          <td class="score teamTwoScore">15</td>
          <td class="team winners">Soham Roshan Kunal</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// Teams
let team = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".team"));

// Scores
let teamOneScore = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".teamOneScore"));
let teamTwoScore = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".teamTwoScore"));
let score = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".score"));

// Matches Played
// Getting all the names into one array
let playerNames = [];
team.forEach((element) => {
  teams = element.textContent;
  let teamsSplit = teams.split(/[ ,]+/);
  playerNames.push(teamsSplit);
});
playerNamesString = playerNames.toString();

finalArray = playerNamesString.split(/[ ,]+/);

// Getting number for each name
function getOccurence(array, value) {
  let count = 0;
  array.forEach((x) => x === value && count++);
  return count;
}
// Writing out matches played for each name
function matchesPlayed(name) {
  let number = getOccurence(finalArray, name);
  let matchesPlayedName = document.querySelector(`.matchesPlayed${name}`);
  return (matchesPlayedName.textContent = number);
}

finalArray.forEach((name) => {
  matchesPlayed(name);
});

// Wins & Losses

let winners = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".winners"));

let winningTeams = [];
winners.forEach((element) => {
  let winnersText = element.textContent;
  let winnersSplit = winnersText.split(/[ ,]+/);
  winningTeams.push(winnersSplit);
});

winnersString = winningTeams.toString();
finalArrayWinners = winnersString.split(/[ ,]+/);

let losers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".losers"));

let losingTeams = [];
losers.forEach((element) => {
  let losersText = element.textContent;
  let losersSplit = losersText.split(/[ ,]+/);
  losingTeams.push(losersSplit);
});

losersString = losingTeams.toString();
finalArrayLosers = losersString.split(/[ ,]+/);

function calculateWins(name) {
  let wins = getOccurence(finalArrayWinners, name);
  let winsName = document.querySelector(`.${name}Wins`);
  return (winsName.textContent = wins);
}

// Losses
function calculateLosses(name) {
  let losses = matchesPlayed(name) - calculateWins(name);
  let lossesName = document.querySelector(`.${name}Losses`);
  return (lossesName.textContent = losses);
}

// Winrate
function calculateWinRate(name) {
  let winRate = (calculateWins(name) / matchesPlayed(name)) * 100;
  let winRateName = document.querySelector(`.${name}Winrate`);
  return (winRateName.textContent = Math.round(winRate) + "%");
}

finalArrayWinners.forEach((name) => {
  calculateWins(name);
  calculateLosses(name);
  calculateWinRate(name);
});

// Sort
let statsTable = document.querySelector(".stats");

function tableSort(table, column, asc = true) {
  const dirModifier = asc ? 1 : -1;
  const tBody = table.tBodies[0]; // 1st body in the table
  const rows = Array.from(tBody.querySelectorAll("tr")); // Selecting every row in tBody

  // Sort each row
  const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {
    // Get table cell at index

    const aColText = a
      .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${column + 1})`)
      .textContent.trim();
    const bColText = b
      .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${column + 1})`)
      .textContent.trim();

    return aColText > bColText ? 1 * dirModifier : -1 * dirModifier;
  });

  // Remove all existing table rows
  // While there is a table row element in tBody, remove each one until we reach the end
  while (tBody.firstChild) {
    tBody.removeChild(tBody.firstChild);
  }

  // Re-add the newly sorted rows
  tBody.append(...sortedRows);

  // Remember how the column is currently sorted
  // Removes any sorting class that may have been previously applied
  statsTable
    .querySelectorAll("th")
    .forEach((th) => th.classList.remove("th-sort-asc", "th-sort-desc"));

  // Adds the ascending sort class
  statsTable
    .querySelector(`th:nth-child(${column + 1})`)
    .classList.toggle("th-sort-asc", asc);

  // Adds the descending sort class
  statsTable
    .querySelector(`th:nth-child(${column + 1})`)
    .classList.toggle("th-sort-desc", !asc);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".table-sortable th").forEach((headerCell) => {
  headerCell.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const tableElement = headerCell.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement; // Going up 3 times on the DOM tree gives us the table element itself, lets you apply sorting code to multiple tables
    const headerIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(
      headerCell.parentElement.children,
      headerCell
    );
    const currentIsAscending = headerCell.classList.contains("th-sort-asc");
    tableSort(tableElement, headerIndex, !currentIsAscending);
  });
});

// Winstreak

// function checkWinstreak(array, name) {
//   for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//     let winStreak = [];

//     winStreak.push(array[i]);
//     if (!array[i].includes(name)) {
//       break;
//     }
//     console.log(winStreak);
//   }
// }

// checkWinstreak(winningTeams, "Roshan");

console.log(playerNames);
console.log(winningTeams);
console.log(losingTeams);
```